# java multithreading basic console program

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm new to multithreading. So here is the problem I'm working on: Store the last four digits of your student ID in two separate classes. For example, if your ID is SE123456789 then store 67 in first Thread1 Class and 89 in Thread2 Class that will be passed to Factorial class later.
Thread1 class will pass 67 to the Factorial class and `printfactorial()` will print factorial of all the numbers from 1 to 67.
Thread2 class will pass 89to the Factorial class and `printfactorial()` will print factorial of all the numbers from 1 to 89.
You should use thread.sleep(10) after each calculation inside the loop.
As you know that you cannot store and print factorial of large numbers in simple integer or long type variables, so you are required to use BigInteger to store and print very long numbers.
`printfactorial()` method must be synchronized so that the results of Thread1 are printed first then the result of Thread2 is calculated and printed.
and here's what I have done so far.
I have four different classes

```
Main
Factorial
Thread1
Thread2
```

Thread1 and Thread2 both extend Thread class.
here's the code I wrote so far:

> Main

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]){
    Factorial factorial = new Factorial();  
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(factorial);
    Thread1 t2 = new Thread1(factorial);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
 }
}
```

> Factorial Class

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Factorial {
    public void printFactorial(int number){
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("1");
        try{
            for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
                bigInteger = bigInteger.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                Thread.sleep(10); 
                System.out.println(bigInteger);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            System.out.println("the interruption has occurred in the thread");
        }
    }
}
```

> Thread1

```
package com.mycompany.factorial;
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    Factorial factorial;
    Thread1(Factorial fact){
        factorial = fact;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(){
        synchronized(factorial){
            try{
                /*my ID is: SE170400080
                so the second last two digits are 00.
                **/
                factorial.printFactorial(00); //here's the problem
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("the interruption has occurred in the thread");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Thread2

```
package com.mycompany.factorial;

public class Thread2 extends Thread {
    Factorial factorial;
    Thread2(Factorial fact){
        factorial = fact;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(){
        synchronized(factorial){
            try{
                factorial.printFactorial(80);
              
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("the interruption has occurred in the thread");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after running the main it builds successfully but does not show the required output.

[image]

help would be really appreciated, I tried best to keep it on point.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAt7w.png):

Comment: Are you sure you're running the project and not just building it? BTW, you don't need to synchronize access to `Factorial.printFactorial` method, since it doesn't manipulate shared data.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin Yes, I build it than running it.

Comment: Do not override `start()`. If you do that, then the `t1.start()` and `t2.start()` calls are just calling your own code, and no thread ever gets created. Override the `Thread.run()` method instead.

Comment: You say, "...I build then running it." What makes you think you are running it? Why don't you put a `println("I am alive!")` statement in `main(...)` at the very beginning, before it does anything else? If you don't see "I am alive!" printed in the console output, then there's no point in asking why the other stuff wasn't printed.

Comment: Re, "...printFactorial(00);  // here's the problem" That's a problem with the assignment—your instructor obviously did not think about that case—but I don't see that it's a problem for your code. Your printFactorial method is supposed to print the factorials of all of the numbers from 1 to N. Well, there _aren't any_ numbers from 1 to 0, so if `printFactorial(0)` doesn't print anything, then it's doing exactly what the assignment said it should do.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes i agreed but the problem is that why its not printing the Thread2.
i mean 1 to 80 ?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the exercise you have been asked to complete, can you [edit] your question and post the expected output? You can use small numbers, for example 4 and 7, rather than 67 and 89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. Override `run` method, rather than `start`: `start` only starts your thread, but the actual code being run belongs to the `run` method. A nice little tutorial is on the Oracle's [website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).
2. In `main`, you create two instances of `Thread1`, a likely copy-pasting error

Comment: Re, "1...run...start." What you say is true, but you haven't told the OP why it's bad to override `start()` or why the "actual code being run belongs to the `run()` method." A little more detail would be nice.

Comment: Re. "2...." There's nothing wrong with the program using two instances of the `Thread1` class. The `Thread11` class and the `Thread2` class are identical. The program output will be the same regardless of whether the `main()` routine uses two instances of `Thread1` or two instances of `Thread2` or one instance of each.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well, "why" - it's because it works that way. Added the link to a tutorial, though. As for the second, they're not the same - they call `printFactorial` with different argument.

Comment: Re "3..." You are advising the OP to implement something different from what the assignment says to implement. The assignment says, "all the numbers from 1 up to the given." There are _no_ numbers in the range from 1 up to 0. Therefore the correct solution should print no factorials when given zero. What the OP _should_ do is plug in a different number, and add a comment that says, "This is not my actual student ID. My actual ID ends in `00`, but thats a bad number to use because ...."

Comment: @SolomonSlow As for the third, fair point, removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but you need to know this:

A `Thread` instance is not a *thread.* A *thread* is an object in the operating system that runs your code. A Java `Thread` instance is an object in your program that you can use to create and manage an operating system *thread.*

The `Thread` instance creates the OS *thread* when you call `t.start()`. Don't override the `start()` method because if you do that, then it will never create the thread. You'll just be calling the method that *you* wrote if you override `start()`.

When you call the *normal* `t.start()` method, and it creates a new thread, then the new thread will call the `t.run()`.  The `run()` method is the one you want to override because it's code is what will be executed in the new thread.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is still not resolved I have tried different numbers instead of 00 it works fine but I am figuring why it's not printing out factorial from 1 to 80. like you said There are no numbers in the range from 1 up to 0.